# Javascript error causing rails link_to functions to stop working

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

This is my first post so apologies if my question formatting is not up to par.

I am having an issue with the JavaScript on my ruby on rails web application at the moment, I have been following the rails tutorial by Michael Hartl Ruby on Rails Tutorial (found [here](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/following_users)). Within chapter 14 he shows users how to implement AJAX functionality to allow `follow/unfollow` buttons to update a view without the user having to refresh the screen.

Anyway, the problem I'm having is that somewhere in my code is a problem which is causing all my rails link_to methods to stop working when clicked. I am not receiving any errors, but am just unable to navigate my site due to the links not working. Its definitely a javascript problem as when removing the line:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
```

from my application.html.erb file my buttons work. I would have just left the javascript to include tag out of my application file but it is needed for some of my other website functionality.

Any help would be appreciated,

thanks

kane

Answer (score 0):

When you click on `link_to` what happens? Check your server log(console unless daemon mode or `log/development.log` otherwise) - what that says, what views checks or renders(that can helps when all request sends as xhr)? If after click nothing is written to the log check your browser console - there are some errors or messages? 
Otherwise, check your js files, maybe somewhere present click listener on the tag `a` that prevented his scenario.

Also, provide your router code, link example and same controller(or link to repo) if all was not helpful

Comment: I don't know what I was doing wrong, but I've gone back onto my rails application and its running fine now. Thanks for your tips Leo, I appreciate your suggestions. Hopefully no further problems occur :)